# wp_get_environment_type is undefined

Tags: plugins, mu-plugins

I don't understand wordpress, why is this `wp_get_environment_type` function `undefined`?

[image]

Isn't this a "native" wordpress function? How can I make it defined? Here is my code inside of a MU-Plugin file:

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
$environment = wp_get_environment_type();
//...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It is a core WP function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_environment_type/), but only after [WordPress version 5.5.0](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_environment_type/#changelog).

If you're using an older version of WordPress, it won't exist yet.

Do this:

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_get_environment_type' ) ) {
    return;
}
$environment = wp_get_environment_type();
//...
```

Or, better still, make sure your WordPress installation is up to date.